# my scss code is not properly nested

Tags: sass

I'm having a hard time getting this working correctly in sass. Who can point me out what I'm doing wrong?

```
.label-info {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1rem;

    & :hover {
        background-color: pink;
    }
}
```

That doesn't work, the hover doesn't work.

```
.label-info {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
.label-info:hover {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

This works, but that's not scss. how do I nest this correctly?

Comment: are you actually compiling your scss into css, and loading the compiled css into your html page?

Answer (score 2):

The space is messing it up- updated works for me:

```
&:hover {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried first:
    .label-info {
     background-color: red;
     border-radius: 1rem;
    &:hover {
         background-color: pink;
 }
} Only it doesn't work. I get the wrong color.